# Error while moving Drupal moving error

Tags: drupal

I was trying to move my Drupal site from my WAMP server to another computer's WAMP server and I followed all the necessary steps but I faced the error below. I tried updating but it didn't work.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in C:\wamp\www\try\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 901
```

I am using PostgreSQL and PhpPgAdmin. Any ideas?

Comment: Another possible related answer : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-cache-get/160347#160347

Answer (score 1):

1. See if Memcache is used in previous server.
2. If not see if some other cacheing mechanism like varnish cache is used

If none of the above:

When you type `drush` in the command line probably you reached the right place to solve you problem. This error arises when drush is not update and this occurs when you install drush from official repository in Ubuntu. The workaround is easy: just install a new version of drush! And to do so, you have to install from backported package of Ubuntu.

Comment: thanx, but i'am not running drupal on Linux i am usning WAMP in windows.

Comment: Then the problem is in your bootstrap your cache.inc files not included properly probably problem with ,virtual host entry or all required file are not included